# WiFi preference not working

Tags: wifi, big-sur

I've prioritized my wifi settings so my computer SHOULD connect to my home wifi if it can, and choose an alternate wifi network (Xfinity, for example) when I'm roaming.

But the computer keeps connecting to Xfinity and ignoring my home wifi until I manually change it over, each time. The preferences list doesn't actually work. I usually find out that it's on the wrong wifi network when I go to print and it hangs up, looking for the printer.

Without removing Xfinity from the known networks, how can I enforce the preferences, so that I actually DO prefer my home network?

Comment: Which version of macOS are you running?

Comment: 11.2.3
And who downvotes a question like this?

Comment: As far as I can see nobody down- or upvoted so far.